# Prove that $g\in P$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $P$ a Sylow $2$-subgroup. If $g$ is an element of $G$ with order a power of $2$ then it lies in some conjugate of $P$. I get this.

But if also $g\in C_G(P)$, then it is true that $g\in P$. Why? I can't see that immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $g\in C_G(P)$, then the subgroup $Q$ generated by $P$ and $g$ is a $2$-group (every element of $Q$ can be written in the form $g^n p$ for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $p\in P$ since $g$ commutes with $P$, and $(g^np)^{2^m}=1$ for $m$ sufficiently large since $g$ and $p$ commute and both have order a power of $2$).  Since $P$ is $2$-Sylow and $Q\supseteq P$, this implies $Q=P$, so $g\in P$.

Comment: Given two elements $g^np$ and $g^mp$ of that set, their product $g^npg^mp'=g^{n+m}pp'$ is also in the set since $g$ and $p$ commute and $pp'\in P$.  Inverses are similar.

Comment: Yes, the definition of $C_G(P)$ is the set of $g$ such that $pg=gp$ for all $p\in P$.

Comment: I meant $\{ g^n p | n \in \mathbb{N}, p \in P\}$ thank you I think I got it